# django get_object() getting called many times

Tags: python, django, class, django-views

I have a model- `Article`, and this code snippet

```py
class ArticleDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Article
    # some code...
    
    def get_object(self):
        article = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_object()
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
        
        print(article.some_count.counts)
        
        return article
```

this code is line printing the value of `article.some_count_counts` 3 times, it means the function `get_object()` is getting called 3 times.

But **why so?** that's my question.

Comment: you show only a fragment of the code so anything would be just a wild guessing. Put [print_stack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack) in the code instead of `print()` to see where it is called.

Comment: Maybe the HitCountDetailView calls the get_object method a few times

Comment: As an aside: why do you _yourself_ first use the superclass implementation to get the object, then get the object again?

Comment: @AKX using get_object is justified, I need to get that article with a specific slug. As HitCountDetailView does nothing but handling views of all articles

Comment: No, repeating that logic is not justified since DetailViews can get objects with slug just fine. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg

Comment: @AKX Ohh! wow, thank you much. so basically I removed the `get_object` method in the first place, and it worked. Django is magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `get_object()` method.

Django `DetailView` itself can get objects with **slug** field.
So calling that function again is redundant.

supporting doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg